# NoClassDefFoundError : org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

Tags: maven, dependency-management

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.file.FileWagon.resolveDestinationPath(FileWagon.java:206)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.file.FileWagon.putDirectory(FileWagon.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.push(AbstractDeployMojo.java:441)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:323)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deployTo(AbstractDeployMojo.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.execute(AbstractDeployMojo.java:166)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.SiteStageMojo.execute(SiteStageMojo.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    ... 28 more
```

This happens when I try to run

```
mvn site site:stage
```

**pom.xml** is:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Appengine Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.lambdaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>lambdaj</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>9000</port>
                <tempWebappDirectory>${basedir}/target/site/tempdir</tempWebappDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-descriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attach-descriptor</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>       
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.codehaus.mojo
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        versions-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>
                                            display-dependency-updates
                                        </goal>
                                        <goal>
                                            display-plugin-updates
                                        </goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- standard plugins -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- appengine -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                    <!-- Comment in the below snippet to bind to all IPs instead of just 
                        localhost -->
                    <!-- address>0.0.0.0</address> <port>8080</port -->
                    <!-- Comment in the below snippet to enable local debugging with a remove 
                        debugger like those included with Eclipse or IntelliJ -->
                    <!-- jvmFlags> <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag> 
                        </jvmFlags -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>index</report>
                        <report>dependencies</report>
                        <report>dependency-convergence</report>
                        <report>dependency-management</report>
                        <report>distribution-management</report>
                        <report>modules</report>
                        <report>plugin-management</report>
                        <report>plugins</report>
                        <report>summary</report>
                        <report>issue-tracking</report>
                        <report>scm</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

In the repository I see that in `commons-lang/commons-lang/` folder
there are four of them 2.1, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6 but 2.1 and 2.4 has no jar in the folder just the other files. There are jars in 2.5 and 2.6 folders.
And in `org/apache/commons/commons-lang3` folder I see one 3.1 with the jar

I have broken this down to the point of absolute basic observation so that someone with the similar experience could help me out.

Comment: Internet access or access to a maven repository does not work. Please show the full error output and not only excerpts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check your version of commons-lang, mine was version 2.6
used sudo find / | grep commons-lang

add to the dependencies before plugins and ensure id starts with I not i:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId> 
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId> 
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Does not build as per wiki there is no 
controller/opendaylight/distribution/opendaylight/target
in order to ./run.sh
So I am looking for that now ??

Answer (score 8):

Since OP did not specify details I guess this may be about running maven on Ubuntu 14.

Maven packaging on Ubuntu seems to have some "issue".
After `apt-get install maven` in Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and attempting to package my project with `mvn package` I got the same exception.

Workaround [from comment on github](https://github.com/mesos/chronos/issues/211) is:

```
sudo ln -s ../../java/commons-lang.jar /usr/share/maven/lib
```

That fixed maven at least in my case.

Comment: this fix the pom.xml problem in wavemaker git version :)

Answer (score 3):

You do not declare `commons-lang` as a dependency. Add

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

To your `pom.xml`

Your pom.xml should looks like:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Appengine Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.lambdaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>lambdaj</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>9000</port>
                <tempWebappDirectory>${basedir}/target/site/tempdir</tempWebappDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-descriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attach-descriptor</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>       
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.codehaus.mojo
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        versions-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>
                                            display-dependency-updates
                                        </goal>
                                        <goal>
                                            display-plugin-updates
                                        </goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- standard plugins -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- appengine -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                    <!-- Comment in the below snippet to bind to all IPs instead of just 
                        localhost -->
                    <!-- address>0.0.0.0</address> <port>8080</port -->
                    <!-- Comment in the below snippet to enable local debugging with a remove 
                        debugger like those included with Eclipse or IntelliJ -->
                    <!-- jvmFlags> <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag> 
                        </jvmFlags -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>index</report>
                        <report>dependencies</report>
                        <report>dependency-convergence</report>
                        <report>dependency-management</report>
                        <report>distribution-management</report>
                        <report>modules</report>
                        <report>plugin-management</report>
                        <report>plugins</report>
                        <report>summary</report>
                        <report>issue-tracking</report>
                        <report>scm</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId> ....... 
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- Appengine Dependencies -->
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>

Comment: its too long for the comment ... just trust me i put it above the <!-- Appengine dependencies --> line

Comment: @VishalDesai Do not add `commons-lang` in '<dependencyManagement>'. Add it outside of the tag.

Comment: well I tried that also ... moved it out of dependency management and same error

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hmm...I've used commons-lang3 library for StringUtils in my project. <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
 <version>3.3.2</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 1):

For me it seems that the problem was in accessing artifact in local maven repository, so I just deleted the whole org/apache folder from local maven repo and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the commons-lang3.jar dependency version in pom.xml. if you are doing code in java simple project add another jar whatever version you are using.
or you can check jar replication shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.6:stage (default-cli) on project a1: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.6:stage failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.6:stage: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils

Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

---

```
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:125)
... 20 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.file.FileWagon.resolveDestinationPath(FileWagon.java:206)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.file.FileWagon.putDirectory(FileWagon.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.push(AbstractDeployMojo.java:452)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:332)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deployTo(AbstractDeployMojo.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.execute(AbstractDeployMojo.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.SiteStageMojo.execute(SiteStageMojo.java:71)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)

`org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` missing when running Maven on Ubuntu

Some Maven goals like `site:stage` fail under Ubuntu 14.04 with

```
A required class was missing while executing
    org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.4:stage: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
```

***This happens if you use the Ubuntu Maven package which misses the `commons-lang` dependency. You can either unpack a stand-alone Maven archive or use the following commands:
    cd /usr/share/maven/lib
    sudo ln -s ../../java/commons-lang.jar .
https://wiki.apache.org/commons/VfsProblems***

Comment: Solved my problem. – naresh meena 5 mins ago